# pdf link not working Joomla 3.5.1

Tags: pdf, joomla

I've had this site (donake.net) up for about a year. Was notified by someone that the link on one of the pages to a PDF wasn't working and a link to another page wasn't working.

When I tried logging in, it wouldn't take my username and password. I realized that I need to update the version of Joomla on my GoDaddy hosting account. Once I updated the version of Joomla to 3.5.1, I was able to login and access the admin side of Joomla. I think the site was attacked because there were a lot of "registered users" that weren't real.

One of the pages was set to unpublished, so I published it and that link started working fine.

The link "VIEW A SAMPLE of the book here" on this page - http://donake.net/just-make-me-a-sammich-book still won't work. I've re-linked the PDF. Deleted the PDF and re-uploaded it with the file name changed and nothing has worked.

One other thing is the icons in the Admin side of Joomla aren't displaying either. Not sure if all of this is tied together or not. My MAIN CONCERN is getting the link to work.

Any help would be greatful!!!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, I ended up calling our hosting company and they helped me edit the .htaccess file to include pdf in the RewriteRule (for me it was on line 3).

Hope this helps because I know it drove me mad trying to fix it.

Good luck!